# How to reverse the collection view cell

Tags: objective-c

i have an array  with 15 elements and I am adding them to collection view cell

```
_imagearray=[@[@"bootimages",@"fall-photography-in-hocking-hills", @"gift",@"hillimages",@"Mercedes-classe-S-W116_large_dettaglio_articolo",@"prinimages",@"resplendent",@"tnb4",@"Tomato-plant",@"Vole",@"waterimages",@"fall-photography-in-hocking-hills", @"gift",@"hillimages",@"Mercedes-classe-S-W116_large_dettaglio_articolo"]mutableCopy];

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

     //[self.collection reloadData];
    homeceeCollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    UIImage *image;
    NSInteger row = [indexPath row];


    NSLog(@"indexpath = %ld", (long)row);

        image = [UIImage imageNamed:_imagearray[row]];

    cell.img.image = image;

    cell.text.text=[_tittlearray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        return cell;
}
```

and I in the next view controller I am taking an image  using camera and saving in to the array and I am passing the array back to the first view controller using `NSNotificationCenter`

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(receivedArray:) name:@"ShareArray" object:nil];

-(void) receivedArray:(NSNotification*)notification
{

        NSMutableArray* userInfo = notification.object;
    UIImage *image = [userInfo firstObject];

        [_imagearray addObject:[userInfo firstObject]];

    NSLog(@"%@",_imagearray);
      [self.collection reloadData];
    _collection.delegate=self;
    _collection.dataSource=self;


    NSLog(@"%@",_imagearray);
}
I am Reloading the collection view cell and the new image doesn't have name  
if (indexPath.row == 15) {
       image= _imagearray[row];

                //[_imagearray insertObject:image atIndex:0];

    }else {
        image = [UIImage imageNamed:_imagearray[row]];


    }
    cell.img.image = image;

    cell.text.text=[_tittlearray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
```

I want to add new image at the top but it is in the bottom

please help me out i am new to  the objective c

Comment: just add the image in location at "0" index and reload the collectionview [_imagearray insertObject:@"imagename" atIndex:0];

Comment: use [_imagearray insertObject:[userInfo firstObject] atIndex:0]; in receivedArray method

Comment: check my answer @satheeskumar naidu. if any doubt ask me

Comment: @hari i have 15 elements in array all the image have there names,when i add the new image and new image doesn't have any name.i want that image as the first item in the cell after relading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check my answer@ satheesKumar Naidu

```
imagearray=[@[@"bootimages",@"fall-photography-in-hocking-hills", @"gift",@"hillimages",@"Mercedes-classe-S-W116_large_dettaglio_articolo",@"prinimages",@"resplendent",@"tnb4",@"Tomato-plant",@"Vole",@"waterimages",@"fall-photography-in-hocking-hills", @"gift",@"hillimages",@"Mercedes-classe-S-W116_large_dettaglio_articolo"]mutableCopy];

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

     //[self.collection reloadData];
    homeceeCollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    UIImage *image;
    NSInteger row = [indexPath row];


    NSLog(@"indexpath = %ld", (long)row);
   // here i have make the changes** 
    if( [_imagearray[row] isKindOfClass:[UIImage class]]){
       image = _imagearray[row]
    }
   else {
        image = [UIImage imageNamed:_imagearray[row]];
    }

    cell.img.image = image;

    cell.text.text=[_tittlearray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        return cell;
}


 -(void) receivedArray:(NSNotification*)notification {

    NSMutableArray* userInfo = notification.object;
   if([userInfo count]>0) {
    UIImage *image = [userInfo firstObject];
    ///[_imagearray addObject:[userInfo firstObject]];  use this it will diretly add to end of the last index
    [_imagearray insertObject:[userInfo firstObject] atIndex:0];  // it will add to firstindex of the array value
    NSLog(@"%@",_imagearray);
    [self.collection reloadData];
     // here do not want add the delegate itself.
    NSLog(@"%@",_imagearray);
    }  // it will check the nil object and to prevent the crash
 }
```

Comment: thanks for you quick response,the main problem is userInfo array nave an image but it doest have any  name

Comment: but in collectionview cellforRowindex path. you have implemented with imagename to show the image in collectionview.

Comment: UIImage *image;
    NSInteger row = [indexPath row];
    
   
    NSLog(@"indexpath = %ld", (long)row);
    if (indexPath.row == 15) {
       image= _imagearray[row];
        
                //[_imagearray insertObject:image atIndex:0];
       
    }else {
        image = [UIImage imageNamed:_imagearray[row]];
  
    }
    cell.img.image = image;
    
    cell.text.text=[_tittlearray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
 
        return cell;  please go through the code

Comment: from userInfo array contains imageURL or imageData or image?

Comment: userinfo array  has uiimage (<UIImage: 0x178e5350> size {1936, 1936} orientation 0 scale 1.000000,)

Comment: my requirement is i want the new image as a zeroth element not as 15th element

Comment: s , i have added the image at index "0" position in receivenotification methods and then reload the collectionview

Comment: always welcome and  kindly accept my answer @satheeskumar naidu

Comment: if i repeat the process i.e adding other image the old is deleting and the new image is placing on the old image but i want two images

Comment: first array count is 15,when i add the image array count is 16 ,when i again add 1 more image array count is 16,i want 17 elements

Comment: when i add first time user info have 1 element and the total count is increasing by 1 i.e imagearray count is 16,when i add other new image array count is increasing by one 1 i.e now imagearray count is 17.but it is printing only 16 objects

Comment: how to print userInfo value and required imageArray value

Comment: i have done it already and in the array it is showing 17 elements and userinfo it is showing 1  element

Comment: i am when i add first image it is printing in the cell when add 1 more image 1 image getting deleted 2 image is printing in the cell

Comment: can you share your  project i will try

Comment: phrkrish@gmail.com

Comment: i sent you my project and i used cocoa pods li is like instagram app,in this what ever videos recored ,captured image have to come to the time tine

Answer (score 0):

```
     -(void) receivedArray:(NSNotification*)notification {

            NSMutableArray* userInfo = notification.object;
        UIImage *image = [userInfo firstObject];

            //[_imagearray addObject:[userInfo firstObject]];
        if(image){
         [_imagearray insertObject:image atIndex:0]; // it will insert element at 0 index and will show first place in collection view

        NSLog(@"%@",_imagearray);
          [self.collection reloadData];
        _collection.delegate=self;
        _collection.dataSource=self;


        NSLog(@"%@",_imagearray);
       }
}
```

Comment: Also place if check to make sure [userInfo firstObject] is not nil before inserting the element in Array else it will crash.